# How do I use setMonth() method in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am currently working on getting the month of the date using the Setter function in Codeigniter 4.
I can't figure out how the $time variable obtained since there is no where it is been defined.

echo $time = $time->setMonth(4);

Am getting an undefined variable error. Please help

Comment: What do you mean by "...using the Setter function in Codeigniter 4"?

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa from the documentation: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/time.html?highlight=setter#setters

Comment: Please read [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to [improve your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76367453/edit). Otherwise, you risk having it closed since it lacks debugging details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first instantiate time, and then you can use the setters as in the documentation.  For example;

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

Use CodeIgniter\I18n\Time;

class Mok extends BaseController
{

    public function time() {

        $time = Time::now('America/Chicago', 'en_US');
        $time = $time->setMonth(4);       // April
        echo $time;
    }
}
```